# Sequential circuit sampling with properties of previous circuit round fixed

Tags: stim

**step 1**: Define a quantum circuit of type: `stim.circuit()`
This circuit measures some qubits. I use `sample = circuit.compile_sampler().sample(1)` to sample a single shot of measurement.

**step 2:** I repeat another round of the circuit by
`circuit += circuit`

**step 3:** If I sample again, I will get two sets of measurements where the previous circuit sampling is lost.

This specifically happens when we use `Depolarize2` circuit operations.

How to fix and store previous round circuit properties in stim during next round sampling, and how to sample only a particular round?

Answer (score 1):

Stim's samplers have no notion of making or restoring checkpoints halfway through a circuit. Typically you just take shots from the entire circuit, and analyze it as a whole.

If you need more complicated control over the execution of the circuit, you can use `stim.FlipSimulator` or `stim.TableauSimulator`. They allow you to do instructions one by one, and to inspect the state of the simulator after each instruction.

Comment: Thanks Craig for your answer. Although I have a follow up. Is it possible to store a circuit instance using python. For example, if I define a circuit [circuit = stim.Circuit()], then I do circuit.append_operation("DEPOLARIZE1", data_qubits, noise_prob). Now can I store an instance of this circuit, which stores which of the operations (e.g. "X" or "Y" or "Z") was acted on the qubits?